# How to create next type - [key : Object]

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to create next type in Objective-C - `[key : Object]` ?

I have such map in Swift and I want to send it (`images`) to Objective-C function (in .mm) file, but how to declare such type parameter in Objective-C? What would be equal?

```
private var images : [Int : UIImage] = [:]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    images = [
        124: UIImage(named: “img1”),
        12: UIImage(named: “img2”)
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header you have to declare :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *originalValues;
```

then in .m file do as stated below :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
_originalValues = @{
                    @124: [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"],
                    @125: [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"],
                    @126: [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"],
                    };
}
```

Comment: *@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *originalValues;* . declare this in .h file

Comment: I need this like function to call from Swift and seems it worked ok, **in .h File**: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *originalValues;`

`- (void) setImages:(NSDictionary *) originalValues;` **in .mm File**: `- (void) setImages:(NSDictionary *) originalValues {
    _originalValues = originalValues;
}`

Comment: but how to access object by id now?

Comment: seems I can't pass int as key `[_originalValues objectForKey:124];`

Comment: replace @124 with  [NSNumber numberWithInt:124] and it will work.

Comment: yes already found it also, it worked, now I can get uiimage in Objective-C (which was initially created in Swift)